# Unable to create project from archetype [org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 -> ]

Tags: eclipse, maven

Tried to create new maven based web project in my eclipse (kepler)
after selecting "**[org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0]"**

after, i haven enter group id=com.weather, artifact id=forecast, and finish

i got error in one dialogue box as

***Unable to create project from archetype [org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 -> ]***

thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you have any more error details somewhere?

Comment: i tried with different group id: com.codehaus.mojo.archetypes

Comment: it has come with com.codehaus.mojo.archetypes   j2ee14 1.3            but with org.apache.maven.archetypes: maven-archetypes-webapp:1.0 not came

Answer (score 0):

i could able to create web project with other group id, artifact id

i.e. com.codehaus.mojo.archetypes webapp-j2ee14 1.3